# DB2, PLSQL : My script doesn't work

Tags: plsql, db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to run a PL/SQL script on my REDHAT VM

This is my script :

```
connect to WWW user XXX using VVV
DECLARE
   message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
/
```

And this is my command :

```
 db2 -td/ -vf test.sql
```

And this is my error:

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DECLARE" was found following "".
>   Expected tokens may include:  "NEW".  SQLSTATE=42601

I tried many things and the result is always the same.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the statement terminator as `/`, but don't use any statement terminator with the `connect to` statement. Append a `/` and it should work.

Also, please check that `PL/SQL` support is turned on. You need to set the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR to enable syntax support for Oracle PL/SQL. See [this section in the DB2 documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053607.html) for details.

Comment: Do you want to run this as script or define a procedure/function?

Comment: The official documentation is a good start http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/r0054808.html

Comment: See my updated answer - I suspect that your database is not enabled for PL/SQL

Comment: A common issue with the DB2 oracle compatibility I have found is that  enabling the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR is not enough. If you have the option, you could do the following:

    db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA
    db2set DB2_DEFERRED_PREPARE_SEMANTICS=YES
 
Then restart DB2 or reboot the DB host, after this, the oracle compatibility seems to take effect correctly for NEW databases only, so you may need to drop and recreate your DB also.

Comment: Additionally, the default statement terminator is ';' (semicolon) so if you are trying to run PLSQL, I have found, that it's necessary to add a '--' (double hyphen) after every semicolon EXCEPT for the very last one at 'END;'.. however this may not apply if you set '/' as the terminator (I haven't tried)